# creating new column based on other grouped variables and multiple conditions

Tags: r

suppose I have following data:

```
df1<- data.frame(province= c(1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5),year= c(2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2003,2003,2003,2004,2005,2005),
                 residence= c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),marriage= c(1,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1),count=c(4,1,3,5,3,2,2,3,2,1,2,4,2,5))
```

in my data `marriage = 1` is `ever-married` and `marriage = 2` is `never-married`. the proportion of `ever-married` can be estimated by column `count`: `ever-married / ever-married + never-married`

what I want is estimating the proportion of `ever-married` based on columns `province`, `year` and `residence` and two conditions:
1- if there is no ever-married based on three columns, the proportion would be `0`
2- if there is no never-married based on three columns, the proportion would be `100`.

my expected output would be like this:

```
    province year  residence    sub
        1   2001         1    0.80
        2   2001         1    0.00
        3   2001         2    0.70
        4   2002         1  100.00
        4   2003         1    0.00
        4   2003         2  100.00
        5   2004         2  100.00
        5   2005         2    0.71
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We group by 'province', 'year', 'residence', create a condition based on `if/else` when 'marriage' values 1, 2 are not present, then return 0, 100 respectively or `else` get the 'count' values that correspond to 'marriage' value of 1, divide by the `sum` of 'count' and then `sum` the proportions

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(province, year, residence)  %>% 
   summarise(sub = if(!any(marriage == 1)) 0 
     else if(!any(marriage == 2)) 100 else 
      sum(count[marriage == 1]/sum(count)), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 4
  province  year residence     sub
     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1        1  2001         1   0.8  
2        2  2001         1   0    
3        3  2001         2   0.7  
4        4  2002         1 100    
5        4  2003         1   0    
6        4  2003         2 100    
7        5  2004         2 100    
8        5  2005         2   0.714
```

Comment: thank you akrun but your output is different with mine

Comment: @mehmo based on your condition, how you are getting 0.8 for the first row

Comment: @mehmo For the first group, i.e. `df1 %>% filter(province ==1 , year == 2001, residence == 1)`. how do you get 0.8

Comment: for first group the proportion would be 4/5. ever-married =4 and sum ever and never married = 5

Comment: @mehmo thanks, now i got the logic.  Updatd the post

Comment: thank you for your great help @akrun